# How to add link inside a div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got a issue with the event bubbling.

I have html like

```
<div id='title-bar1'> 
    title bar
   <div class='editDiv'>
        <a class='edit' href='#'>Edit</a>
   </div>
</div>


$('#edit').on('click', function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
       //do B
})


$('#title-bar1').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //do A       
})
```

`title-bar1` is a div that wrap `edit` link. My problem is that I can't seem to `do B` when I click my `edit` link. It always `do A`. I add `stopPropagation` and still not working. Can someone help me about this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `edit` is a class, not an id. The selector should be `$('.edit')`.

Comment: You don't have control with ID="edit" only class. Perhaps you meant `$('.edit')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong on this and I am sure someone else will correct me, however, based on your code you have "edit" as a class.

When referencing a class it would be $('.edit').onclick

In CSS, to modify an element that has an id=edit, one would do #edit{ color:red;}

Where a class would be .edit { color:red; }

So the function to where you stop progagation never gets fired off.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id='title-bar1'> 
    title bar
   <div class='editDiv'>
        <a class='edit' href='#'>Edit</a>
   </div>
</div>


$('.edit').on('click', function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
       //do B
})


$('#title-bar1').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //do A       
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$('#edit').on('click', function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
   //do B
```

})

To:

```
$('.edit').on('click', function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
   //do B
```

})

Class = .  //before selector

ID    = #  //before selector

Hope This Helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id='title-bar1'> 
    title bar
   <div class='editDiv'>
        <a class='edit' href='#'>Edit</a>
   </div>
</div>


$('.edit').on('click', function(e){
// ^edit is a class not an id
     e.stopPropagation();
       //do B
})


$('#title-bar1').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //do A       
})
```